# Show that if $a$ is divisible by $5^x$, then the last $x$ digits are divisible by $5^x$.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Show that if $a$ is divisible by $5^x$, then the last $x$ digits are divisible by $5^x$.

I have two questions;

1. Is my first proof correct?
2. How could you employ modular arithmetic to prove this statement? I feel it would be much the same, except with a few $\text{mod}\hspace{0.1cm} 5^x$'s planted throughout the proof.

$\boxed{\text{Direct Proof}}$

Let $a = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_i\cdot10^i = a_0\cdot10^0 + a_1\cdot10^1 + ... + a_n\cdot10^n$. Then, $ a - \sum_{i = y}^{n} a_i\cdot10^i$ leaves the last $y$ digits of $a$.

We have that $5^y|10^i = 2^i\cdot5^i$ for $i\geq y$. However, we know that $5^x|a$, hence, $5^x$ must divide $ a - \sum_{i = y}^{n} a_i\cdot10^i$, which are clearly the last $x$ digits of $a$. $\square$

Comment: The proof looks good to me

Comment: Looks good to me too. Regarding your second question, perhaps this would work:

If $5^x\mid a$, we need to show that if $a\equiv k\pmod{10^x}$ where $0\leq k\lt 10^x$, then $5^x\mid k$. Notice that, $$a-k\equiv 0\pmod{2^x5^x}\\ \iff a-k\equiv 0\pmod{2^x,5^x}\implies a\equiv k\pmod{5^x}\implies k\equiv a\equiv 0\pmod{5^x}$$

Answer (score 1):

1. The proof is correct.
2. Using modular arithmetic:

$$5^x \mid 10^x,$$
so
$$a\ \mathrm{mod}\  5^x = (a\ \mathrm{mod}\ 10^x)\ \mathrm {mod}\ 5^x.$$